# Pervasive SQL v10, Inner Join doesn't work

Tags: sql, pervasive, pervasive-sql

i am trying to join to tables in Pervasive SQL.

```
select GUID, b.BankName from Ad 
INNER JOIN AdBankKto b ON 
b.AdGUID = Ad.GUID
```

But i always get an error:
*[LNA][Pervasive][ODBC Engine Interface]Error in expression: GUID*

If i delete GUI, i get this error:
*[LNA][Pervasive][ODBC Engine Interface]Error in predicate: b . AdGUID = Ad . GUID*

Both columns are UNIQUEIDENTIFIER, i absolutly have no idea why this doesn't work, any ideas?

LG

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing I noticed is that the `GUID` in your `SELECT` could be ambiguous.  You should alias the field with the table name so something like:

```
select Ad.GUID, b.BankName from Ad 
INNER JOIN AdBankKto b ON 
b.AdGUID = Ad.GUID
```

Once properly aliased, the query works for me using PSQL v11.  Make sure that the `AdGUID` exists in the `AdBankKTo` table.  I tested with stub tables and it worked correctly for me:

```
Create table AdBankKto (AdGUID uniqueidentifier, BankName char(100));
create table Ad (GUID uniqueidentifier, Something char(100));
insert into AdBankKto values ('9AA7B72F-64D4-4F3D-B5BB-716E0309D588', 'BankName');
insert into Ad values ('9AA7B72F-64D4-4F3D-B5BB-716E0309D588', 'Something');

select Ad.GUID, b.BankName from Ad 
INNER JOIN AdBankKto b ON 
b.AdGUID = Ad.GUID
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, when I run the query I get the second error mentioned above

Comment: The above scipt also works for me, it seems to be a problem with the GUID in the Database. I just tried this simple thing :  

select * from Ad where GUID = '5E4005F9-D6B5-4E49-AED2-544B07DED6B6' 
and I get the following error:
[LNA][Pervasive][ODBC Engine Interface]Error in predicate: GUID = '5E4005F9-D6B5-4E49-AED2-544B07DED6B6'

Comment: So, my query works but your query doesn't.  Is that right?  That says there's something wrong with your table.  What is the structure of the "Ad" table?  You should edit your question to include that information.  Also, are you fully patched on your PSQL v10?  I've been using V11.30.